# Itemize/Disaggregate Aggregate Data Table

Tags: python, sql-server, aggregate

I have a table of aggregate data:

```
KWid     Orders    Revenue
12345    10        150
23468    5         200
```

This data is stored in one vendor's reports, but we are migrating to a new vendor. To ingest the transactional data, the new vendor needs each order listed on a single line, i.e. KWid 23468 with 5 orders would show as follows:

```
KWid     Orders    Revenue   OrderID
23468    1         40        1
23468    1         40        2
23468    1         40        3
23468    1         40        4
23468    1         40        5
```

Note, the total revenue for the 5 orders (200) was split equally across the 5 lines. Also, a unique order ID has to be created for each individual row.

I have done this in the past, but can't seem to locate my code anywhere. How would I accomplish with the following stipulations:

1. Must by in SQL Server or Python
2. Cannot include a counter table as shown in this solution (too many transactions to create such a table efficiently) - [disaggregate summarised table in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606364/disaggregate-summarised-table-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Just join to a tally table and this is painless.

Answer (score 1):

Joining to a tally table makes this pretty straight forward. You can read more about tally tables [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/).

I keep one as a view on my system. Here is my version.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Next we need a table with your table so I just tossed together quick table variable. In your query you would write this against your base table.

```
declare @Something table (KWid int, Orders int, Revenue decimal(7,2))

insert @Something values
    (12345, 10, 150)
    , (23468, 5, 200)
```

Now we have the problem setup and this becomes fairly easy. This query should produce the data you stated you want.

```
select s.KWid
    , OrderNum = t.N 
    , Revenue = convert(numeric(7, 2), round(s.Revenue / s.Orders, 2))
from @Something s
join cteTally t on t.N <= s.Orders
order by s.KWid
    , t.N
```

Comment: That is an absolutely brilliant solution! Thanks Sean!

Comment: Cool glad you like it. If this works you should consider marking this as the answer so others know this solved your problem.